# Why am I suddenly getting an error about no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: surveymonkey

Yesterday, I was happily making API calls to SurveyMonkey from my local development machine (http://localhost:nnnn)

This morning however (after changing exactly nothing), I'm suddenly getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8500' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 596.
```

The code I'm using which generates this error is the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        survey_id: 'nnnnnnnn',
        respondent_ids: respondents  //respondents is an array defined elsewhere
    }),
    headers:{
        Authorization: 'bearer ' + local.SurveyMonkey.AccessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(survey, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#SMResults').empty().append('<br />'+textStatus);
        $p.fnLog(survey.data);
        $p.fnLoadView('surveyView.cfm','SMResults',survey);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        $('#SMResults').empty().append('Oh nos!! Something went wrong!');
        $p.fnLog(jqXHR);
        $p.fnLog('----------------------');
        $p.fnLog(textStatus);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        $('#SMResults').append("<br /><br />We're done.");
    }
});
```

Again, this code was working brilliantly last night. My attempts to turn this into a JSONP call failed. :(

Any idea what's going on? Why could I happily make these calls yesterday, but not today?

Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE:**  It turns out upon further inspection of the response headers I'm getting:
`X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_596_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND`

Which is why there's not the appropriate Access-Control header in the response. Any idea what's up with Mashery? or Where I should be looking?

**UPDATE 2:**  I'm feeling much more confident that this is a SurveyMonkey/Mashery problem. I just now visited the [SurveyMonkey API Console](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api_console) page and it informed me that the console is experiencing a problem and that they're working to fix it.

I'm guessing that this is just a symptom of a larger problem.

Comment: This is a CORS issue. CORS is a technology that is implemented server side (at surveymokey) and they return to the browser whether  or not the domain the browser is from is allowed to access their resource. You can bypass this in chrome at least, there is a way to start chrome in an insecure mode. I don't know why it suddenly stopped working for you though, almost sounds like surveymonkey is having issues. You cannot change anything in your code to get past this.

Comment: I was afraid of that Kyle. 

I'd already done some [reading on CORS](http://bexhuff.com/2012/01/mashup-standards-part-2-crossorigin-resource-sharing-cors), and thought that _I_ had to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so I tried adding that to my headers but it didn't work... obviously.

I'm really hoping that someone from SurveyMonkey can explain to me why this was working fine yesterday, but not today.

I would hate to have to do development directly on my production server. I think in general that's just a bad idea.

Comment: You could hack at this in your dev environment by using fiddler as a proxy and spoofing the domain with fiddler and having fiddler include the allow origin header with an asterisk as a value.
I think all of that will work, but not sure on the details. I agree, development in your production environment is always bad news.

Comment: cjordan, this error is not related (I don't think) to the problem affecting the API console. Please file a ticket by email me at api-support@surveymonkey.com with details including the API key you're using.

Comment: Thank you Tony! I will do that right now. :)